# How to select last three row automatically on a give range in EXCEL VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I created a code to select and paste data from one sheet to another. But this code is always selecting last three values in row. 
I need to select the data based on given range. Eg C5:C15 not for the entire c column. Help me

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim LastRow1, LastRow2, LastRow3 As Long
Dim Last3Rows1, Last3Rows2, Last3Rows3 As Range

LastRow3 = Sheets("AVG-PO").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastRow1 = Sheets("AVG-PO").Range("A" & LastRow3).End(xlUp).Row
LastRow2 = Sheets("AVG-PO").Range("B" & LastRow3).End(xlUp).Row

Set Last3Rows3 = Sheets("AVG-PO").Range("C" & LastRow3).Offset(-2, 0).Resize(3, 1)
Set Last3Rows1 = Sheets("AVG-PO").Range("A" & LastRow3).Offset(-2, 0).Resize(3, 1)
Set Last3Rows2 = Sheets("AVG-PO").Range("B" & LastRow3).Offset(-2, 0).Resize(3, 1)

Last3Rows1.Select
Selection.Copy Sheets("Data").Range("A30")

Last3Rows2.Select
Selection.Copy Sheets("Data").Range("B30")

Last3Rows3.Select
Selection.Copy Sheets("Data").Range("C30")

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: How do you determine what the first value is?

Comment: I dont need first value, only last three on a given range

Comment: Just use `LastRow3 = 15`?  But if you know you want the last 3 rows in C5:C15, just use `Sheets("AVG-PO").Range("A13:C15").Copy Sheets("Data").Range("A30")`

Comment: Bro, Actually its a pivot table. so the data will be automatically updated. Sometime if the last value is deleted then it must calculate the previous 3 values. So i cant give only the last 3 range.

Comment: Then, instead of `Range("C" & Rows.Count)`, use something like `Range("C16")`.

Comment: why are you setting the values of `LastRow1` and `LastRow2` ?  your code does not use them

Comment: @jsotola YA u r right, i will delete that. but plz help me if u know

Comment: it is not clear what you mean by this `always selecting last three values in row`

Comment: replace your whole program with this `Sheets("AVG-PO").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-2,-2).Resize(3,3).copy  Sheets("Data").Range("A30")`

Comment: @jsotola I think your concept of the single statement is correct, but I think the OP needs to use something other than `Rows.Count` - I get the impression that they have other stuff in column C below row 15, and they only want to find the last row above row 15 - i.e. get the last row of a shrinking / expanding pivot table.  (So I think they probably want `Range("C16")` instead of `Range("C"  & Rows.Count)`.)

Comment: @jsotola 
Thank you man your code is working but it is calulating for entire c column. I have two table on c column and i need to calculate for table 1 alone.
Table 1 range C4:C15 and table 2 range from C19:c28. So only i am asking specific range. If i delete the table 2 the i can automatically calculate on table 1. 
But i cant delete table 2.

Comment: @Deepak Have you tried using `"C16"`?

Comment: @YowE3K Yes bro i tried But i am getting Runtime error 1004 application defined or object defined error

Comment: Perhaps add a screenshot of your data into the question - it will help us work out a valid location to `End(xlUp)` from.

Comment: @YowE3K Bro, i added. Check it now and help me. i need to calculate for table 1 alone last 3 rows

Comment: Try using `Sheets("AVG-PO").Range("C3").End(xlDown)` instead of `Sheets("AVG-PO").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)` (in either your original code or @jsotola's one-liner).  (But I'm not sure why `Sheets("AVG-PO").Range("C16").End(xlUp)` didn't work.)

Comment: If that doesn't work, I think you are going to have to loop through each row, checking to see which is the last one used.

Comment: @Deepak, i am kind of angry at you (not much though ... lol)  ... why did you not post the picture in the start and saved everyone a bunch of time .... looking at the picture tells me that your program does not work correctly .... you will not capture `nov/dez 2016`

Comment: @jsotola actually thats what i need. Thanks for the code. One more help, i need to select values from E, D and A column. can you tell me,  where to change the values

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i quite understand what range you want but you might be able to use this.

```
Sub test()
    Dim NextFree As Long
    Dim TableStartRange As Long

    For i = 1 To 100
    Select Case Range("A" & i).Value
        Case "Table1"
            TableStartRange = i + 1 'finds table1 in A2 and then +1 before the actual table start in column C
    End Select

    NextFree = Range("C" & TableStartRange & ":C" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row ' returns the value 14 since its the first free row in column C

End Sub
```

Comment: You could also change the Select-Case to case Table2 and `NextFree` will hold the value 29